# height cutting out on scrolling down

Tags: css

i am using a left admin panel and i want the height to be 100%, such that it not only shows 100% in thew window,  but also when you scroll it, it should not cut-out.
but my left panel is cutting out when i am scrolling it. here is the css:

```
.adminmenuback {
    width: 30%;
    background: url(../images/leftpanel_bg.png) left top repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

the thing is that there has to be a accordion in this left panel, so a large amount of listing can be in this left panel. i want the window to simply scroll vertically when content in left panel increases. i tried to use position: relative, but in it, `height:100%` does not work and height increases according to content. i also cannot use `position: fixed`, as i want the scroll to occur when left panel increases in content, and  also because i dont want scroll specifically on left panel.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBU2q/

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle ?

Comment: Care to show us what you currently have in jsfiddle? Or rather, how it  currently looks.

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBU2q/. Just scroll down, and you will see the left grey area cuttong-off.

Comment: The `div` right after your `div.adminmenuback`, assign it to the same `background-color`

`div.adminmenuback > div { background-color: #333 }` - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBU2q/1/

Answer (score 0):

change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`. It will work

Comment: i dont want the fixed position, i explained it in the question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about left panel increase

Comment: hi jofryHS, try decreasing the content and then see if the color still shows up on scrolling down. i tried it and it doesnt..

Comment: by left panel increase, i mean when the content in left panel increases